# Write-Verbose freezes PowerShell Workflow

Tags: powershell, powershell-workflow

I just stumbled upon this strange behavior of PowerShell Workflows and now I'm curious if anyone else can reproduce the behavior and maybe even explain it to me.

To describe the situation I've created two workflows that are almost identical. The only difference is that the PSCredential object is created in the workflow scope in the first and in the inlinescript in the second.

First I define the Workflows with the following code:

```
workflow WorkflowCred
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param()
    $Password    = 'test' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credential  = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'test',$Password
    InlineScript 
    {
        Function Test-Verbose 
        {
            [CmdletBinding()]
            Param(
                $Credential
            )
            Write-Output 'Start'
            $Credential.GetType().FullName
            Write-Verbose 'Testing'
            Write-Output 'End'
        }
        Test-Verbose -Credential $Using:Credential
    }
}

workflow InlineCred
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param()
    InlineScript 
    {
        Function Test-Verbose 
        {
            [CmdletBinding(
            )]
            Param(
                $Credential
            )
            Write-Output 'Start'
            $Credential.GetType().FullName
            Write-Verbose 'Testing'
            Write-Output 'End'
        }
        $Password = 'test' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
        $Credential  = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'test',$Password
        Test-Verbose -Credential $Credential
    }
}
```

Now to the strangeness. I can run the following Three commands without any problem:

```
WorkflowCred
InlineCred
WorkflowCred -Verbose
```

But if I run the second workflow with -Verbose my console freezes until I hit CTRL+C??

```
InlineCred -Verbose
```

I can see this behavior if all of the following conditions are true:

- I run a function from within an InlineScript (in a PowerShell Workflow)
- One of the parameters are given an object of the type PSCredential as value
- The PSCredential object is created within the inlinescript
- The function is Writing to the Verbose stream

I've tried this in PowerShell version 3 and 4.